# How to apply gradient map on a grey scale image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I've searched for any possible solution for that, but all the answers are not really clear or incomplete.

So, say I have the image uploaded into memory:

```
image = Image.open('image.jpg')
```

How do I apply this gradient (#582f91 to #00aeef):

[image]

To this image:

[image]

So it becomes this:

[image]

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously solved this problem using a cython script (as need to update at high frame rate) to achieve this. Here the input `cmap` to the funciton is a flattened array of a matrix where each row corresponds to a colour and  coloumns to R G B values. I used a website to generate the gradient though can't remember which one. The image was flattened for speed and scaled between 0 and 255 int values.

To be able to import and use the cython function you will need to run the setup script from command line, once you have install cython using pip i.e.

```
pip install cython
pyhton setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

This should then produce a c file and .so file.

Cython code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

DTYPE1 = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE1_t

DTYPE2 = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE2_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)

def mat_to_im(np.ndarray[DTYPE2_t, ndim=1] data, np.ndarray[DTYPE2_t, ndim=1] cmap):

    cdef int wid = data.size
    cdef int x, x1, y

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE2_t, ndim=1] im = np.zeros([wid*3], dtype=DTYPE2)

    for x in range(wid):

        x1 = x*3
        y = data[x]*3

        im[x1] = cmap[y]
        im[x1+1] = cmap[y+1]
        im[x1+2] = cmap[y+2]

return im
```

Setup file:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
    name='image convert',
    version='1',
    description='color map images',
    author='scooper',
    install_requires=['numpy'],
    ext_modules=cythonize([
        Extension("image_convert", ["image_convert.pyx"], include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])])
)
```

This should help with any issues (I've cut the setup from larger code file and haven't tested it): http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html

Comment: So basically had to individually reassign pixel values using a mapping. The returned image was then reshaped to the original image dimensions.

Comment: Umm, ok. I've never used Cython before. Can you give me a quick guide, how do I use your function?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply if your still looking for solution or faster one than matplotlib I've edited the answer to include setup script?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [LinearSegmentedColormap](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html)  :

```
# make a cmap
mycm=matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('',['#582f91', '#00aeef'])

# apply on a canal
imgrad=mycm(image[:,:,0])
```